# Change color of navigation in laravel instances for staging & live server

Tags: php, css, laravel

So as the title says im looking for a way to swap the color of the laravel navigation bar based on whether it is the live or staging server. We currently have a staging server to test code before creating a pull requst in bitbucket and pushing it to a live server that is currently in production. I would love to simply make the navigation bar a different color so we can easily differentiate the sites.
Has anyone done this in laravel? Is there anyway i can assign a theme color based on the server type?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done changing the color, but we have something similar to your question.

We use `APP_ENV=staging` in the `.env` file. So in your blade you should be able to do something like this:

```php
class="nav nav-default @if(env('APP.ENV') == 'staging') 'nav-warning' @endif"
```